# Module inside module shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to call a module from inside a module and having some problems.

This first code is working, it displays an app with a button that creates a popup. Inside the popup is a plot and a slider input. The popup-plot is defined in it's own module.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

uiForModal <<- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(
        fluidRow(
            plotOutput(outputId = ns("plot")),
            sliderInput(
                inputId =ns( "clusters"),
                label = "Number of clusters",
                min = 2, max = 6, value = 3, width = "100%"
            )
        )
    )   
}

serverForModal <<- function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        print(head(iris))
        plot(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length,
            data = iris, col = Species,
            pch = 20, cex = 2)
        points(kmeans(iris[, 1:2], input$clusters)$centers,
            pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
    })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("showPlot", "showPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output){
    observeEvent(input$showPlot, {
        show_alert(
            title = "Some Title",
            text = tags$div(
                uiForModal("test1")
            ),
            html = TRUE,
            width = "80%"
        )
    })
    callModule(serverForModal, "test1")
}
runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

The problem occurs when I try to put the button inside its own module. The code below is my failed attempt at this. I think the problem is something to do with the namespace. In the code below, the button calls the UI with the popup and slider, but the plot doesn't show. So I think the problem is in the server namespace for the plot. Can someone please help me out?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

uiForModal <<- function(id) {
    print(id)
    ns <- NS(id)
    print(ns("plot"))
    tagList(
        fluidRow(
            plotOutput(outputId = ns("plot")),
            sliderInput(
                inputId =ns( "clusters"),
                label = "Number of clusters",
                min = 2, max = 6, value = 3, width = "100%"
            )
        )
    )   
}

serverForModal <<- function(input, output, session) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
        print(head(iris))
        plot(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length,
            data = iris, col = Species,
            pch = 20, cex = 2)
        points(kmeans(iris[, 1:2], input$clusters)$centers,
            pch = 4, cex = 4, lwd = 4)
    })
}

uiForButton <<- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(
        fluidRow(
            actionButton(ns("showPlot"), "showPlot")
        )
    )
}

serverForButton <<- function(input, output, session, ns) {
    observeEvent(input$showPlot, {
        show_alert(
            title = "Some Title",
            text = tags$div(
                uiForModal(ns("test2"))
            ),
            html = TRUE,
            width = "80%"
        )
    })
    callModule(serverForModal, ns("test2"))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    uiForButton("test1")
)
server <- function(input, output){
    callModule(serverForButton, "test1", NS("test1"))
}
    
runApp(shinyApp(ui, server))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
callModule(serverForModal, ns("test2"))
```

to

```
callModule(serverForModal, "test2")
```

Comment: There is generally no need to use `ns()` in the module server functions.  Please see [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html)  for further details; check nesting modules section.